# Why can't you use relaxed atomic operations to synchronize memory, if there is a thread join in between?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-model, stdatomic

I'm watching this Herb Sutter talk: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2

Looking at two examples (around 1:15 mark), one makes sense to me and the other does not.

**First example (makes sense):**

Note `count` is an atomic int.

Here, using relaxed memory ordering for the load/store on count is said to be ok since thread exit happens before returning from a join on a thread. That means the relaxed adds happen before the relaxed load.

Child thread:

```
while (...) {
  if (...) {
    count.fetch_add(1, memory_order_relaxed);
  }
}
```

Main thread:

```
int main() {
  launch_workers();
  join_workers();
  cout << count.load(memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

**Second example (unclear):**

Note `dirty` and `stop` are atomic booleans.

Here, the talk says that the store and load on `dirty` must respectively use release and acquire ordering, since `dirty` is used to publish some data that is read for cleanup.

Child thread:

```
while(!stop.load(memory_order_relaxed)) {
  if (...) {
    // publish some data
    dirty.store(true, memory_order_release)
  }
}
```

Main thread:

```
int main() {
  launch_workers();
  stop = true;
  join_workers();
  if (dirty.load(memory_order_acquire)) {
    // read published data to clean up
  }
}
```

My question is, in the second example why can't you apply the same 'happens before' relationship between the thread exit and returning from a join on a thread to synchronize the memory?

The way I thought it would work with relaxed memory ordering on the operations of `dirty` is:

[Child thread does some work, including publishing data]

[Child thread exit] **-(happens before)->** [Return from join on child thread in `join_workers()` call]

[Main thread both sees `dirty` as true and can safely read the published data to do cleanup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Around 1:17:25, he says "now, because you happen to know I've got a release-acquire by joining the threads, I've injected a release-acquire in there; that may be good enough and you can just go to relaxed". So he seems to be saying, in the end, that it's actually fine if `dirty` is accessed with relaxed memory ordering.

Comment: He is indeed making a point about general discipline - "you may be looking at other memory". In the actual example, relaxed will work just fine, because full memory barrier is there anyway.

Comment: This is printed in the slide: 'dirty can be acq/rel (probably not relaxed as it usually published data).' That seems to indicate that something about publishing data is the distinction between relaxed vs acq/rel, but it could just be a mixup in the notes.

Comment: On a second watch, it does seem to be a point on general discipline. Thanks for the clarification, I was puzzled.